# Apache (httpd) failing to start on boot - CentOS 7

Tags: centos, apache-httpd

i've just installed CentOS 7, so still getting to grips with it, but can't seem to figure out why Apache won't start on boot.

I have enabled the service via systemctl, and if I start it manually then it starts fine:

```
[root@CentOS7 pav]# systemctl status httpd.service
httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2015-06-02 14:14:27 BST; 10min ago
  Process: 22635 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 22641 (httpd)
   Status: "Total requests: 1; Current requests/sec: 0; Current traffic:   0 B/sec"
   CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
           ââ22641 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ââ22642 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ââ22644 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ââ22645 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ââ22646 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ââ22647 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ââ22648 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ââ22649 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

Jun 02 14:14:27 CentOS7 systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
```

These are the errors in `/var/log/messages`:

```
Jun  2 09:36:46 CentOS7 httpd: (99)Cannot assign requested address: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 192.168.1.77:80
Jun  2 09:36:46 CentOS7 httpd: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Jun  2 09:36:46 CentOS7 httpd: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Jun  2 09:36:46 CentOS7 systemd: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

Comment: How is `192.168.1.77` being assigned to this machine?

Comment: Hi @Bratchley - it's set as a static IP on `eno1`

Comment: Well I mean, are you using the ifcfg scripts, `networkd`, `NetworkManager` etc etc

Comment: i've edited the `ifcfg-eno1` script, which looks like this 
    `GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
    IPV6INIT=no
    DNS1=192.168.1.1
    UUID=d706824e-85a3-48d5-8618-b8fcad310da7
    BOOTPROTO=none
    NAME=""
    MACADDR=""
    TYPE=Ethernet
    DEVICE=eno1
    MTU=""
    NETMASK=255.255.255.0
    DEFROUTE=yes
    IPADDR=192.168.1.77
    IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
    ONBOOT=yes`

Comment: Well basically, it looks like there's some sort of race condition going on where the `httpd` service is getting started before the `network` service runs. That's why starting apache after the server has already started works. It's going to be a bit until I can get to a RHEL7 machine but you may want to look at that.

Comment: You may try a `systemctl list-dependencies httpd.service` to make sure `network` really is set to start before httpd.

Comment: Thanks @Bratchley but `network` actually isn't listed there at all!

Comment: FIXED! The problem was indeed Apache attempting to start before the network was up. Running `systemctl enable NetworkManager-wait-online.service` fixed the issue. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied from the comments above for clarity...

The problem was indeed Apache attempting to start before the network was up. Running `systemctl enable NetworkManager-wait-online.service` fixed the issue.

Thanks to @Bratchley for their help.

Answer (score 0):

in the http.conf we have two line of ip configure like:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
Listen 80
```

Comment one of them may solve problem.